# same module name with different namespace conflicting in magento

Tags: php, magento

if we have two modules with same name but different namespace , would they conflict?

for example:

1. `A_Module_Helper_Data`
2. `B_Module_Helper_Data`

whats happening now is that, when i call `Mage::helper('module')->someMethod();` it says
`someMethod` not found in `A_Module_Helper_Data` while the method exists in `B_Module_Helper_Data`.

How magento differentiates this?
what is the possible solution?

Comment: you have two good answers here feel free to accept one of them as correct, when people already bothered to teach you something

Comment: i must apologize for the delay. i really appreciate your time for the answer. that means a lot. please don't take me wrong for delaying this i have my reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is totally possible to run 2 module with the same name in different namespace, but you have to be carefull.

Like Netismine said, it's the config.xml of the 2 modules that is the most important.

If your 2 modules shares the same helper xml identifier node (eg `<giftmessage>`) and you don't do any rewrite : magento will load the helper of the last module (keep in mind that magento merge ALL its XML files in alphabetically order and/or Dependance orders).

For your case you have 2 solutions to be sure to call the right helper :

- module B rewrite module A (`<rewrite>` mechanisms in the module B config.xml + PHP class B extends PHP class A) in order to take "ownership" of the `giftmessage` helper layer identifier
- register the module B helper layer with a different identifier : (eg `<b_giftmessage>`) and use it in your PHP code

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

It's how you register your module in config.xml. In particular, in helper example, take a look at this part of config.xml for GiftMessage module:

```
<helpers>
    <giftmessage>
    <class>Mage_GiftMessage_Helper</class>
    </giftmessage>
</helpers>
```

notice the `<giftmessage>` part - that's the hook you're looking for. So, when you type `$this->helper('giftmessage')` it will look for a class that was registered the first (or last, doesn't really matter) under that key.