# how to resolve front router conflict when two module with same name in diff namespace

Tags: magento

i have same situation with this question ([same module name with different namespace conflicting in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711524/same-module-name-with-different-namespace-conflicting-in-magento) )

but my problem is how to solve the front controler conflict.i don't want to rewrite the other module but still want to keep the same module name.

ie:the module name is moduleabc,so the url would be

moduleabc/controller/action/

```
    <routers>
        <moduleabc>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>A_moduleabc</module>
                <frontName>moduleabc</frontName>
            </args>
        </moduleabc>
     </routers>
```

i have tried to edit config.xml as below

```
    <routers>
        <moduleabc>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>B_moduleabc</module>
                <frontName>moduleabc</frontName>
            </args>
        </moduleabc>
     </routers>
```

and i found that when magento try to instantiate source model for adminhtml,ie.

moduleabc/source_trans

will be parsed to

A_Moduleabc_Source_Trans class

THE CONFIG.XML for both:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <moduleabc>
            <class>A_Moduleabc_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>Moduleabc_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </moduleabc>

<global>
    <models>
        <moduleabc>
            <class>B_Moduleabc_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>Moduleabc_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </moduleabc>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the  `<frontName>moduleabc</frontName>` with some other and on frontend you can access your module with new frontname. thanks